# When attempting to apply the class attribute to a paragraph, the text remains black instead of the assigned color

Tags: html, css

Here is my information

```css
    
    .error{
        color:rgb(20, 213, 220);
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>CSS Basics</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div>
            <p class="error">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</p>
            <p>12345678901234567890123456</p>
            <p>doremifasolatidodotilasofa</p>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I changed your code into a stack snippet. It works fine.

Comment: what is a stack snippet?

Answer (score -1):

Add css in style tag

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>CSS Basics</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <p class="error">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</p>
        <p>12345678901234567890123456</p>
        <p>doremifasolatidodotilasofa</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<style>
.error{
    color:rgb(20, 213, 220);
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm using a styles.css file instead of adding the tag---it works when i run it here, but in Visual Studio Code it only shows up as black text. Any idea as to why that is?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

Comment: Just edited it---still nothing.

Answer (score -2):

Oh my bad! I fixed it---I had just forgotten to put the styles.css file in the same folder as my .html file, haha '^_^ my bad